# Task about Hartley information(logarithm from cardinality of the set) of a number of paths in a graph and about limit linked with this information.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, information-theory

Let $L_n$ be the number of all paths of length n in a directed graph(below).
It is needed to find $lim_{n \to \infty}\chi(L_n)/n$ where $\chi(L_n)$ is Hartley information in $L_n$ set. (If I am not mistaken, $\chi(L_n) = log(|L_n|)$)

[image]

I tried to find formula for $L_n$. To manage this aim I represented my graph as the adjacency matrix (A):
$\begin{array}{|l | r|} \hline 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 \\ \hline \end{array}$
 Then I found its Jordan canonical normal form($J_A):
$\begin{array}{|l | r|} \hline \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} & 0\\ \hline 0 & \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\\ \hline \end{array}$

and the transition matrix(C): 
$\begin{array}{|l | r|} \hline 1 & \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}} \\ \hline 1 & \frac{2}{1- \sqrt{5}} \\ \hline \end{array}$.

I did it with an aim to make next countings more simple, because
$A^n = C^{-1}\cdot J_A^n \cdot C$.  (1)

Then I found $A^n$ with help of (1) formula and summed all elements of my matrix. This sum is(if I am not mistaken): $\frac{10 \cdot \sqrt{5} + 22}{\sqrt{5}(1+\sqrt{5})^2} \cdot (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n + \frac{8 - 4 \cdot \sqrt{5}}{(\sqrt{5} + 5) \cdot (1 - \sqrt{5}} \cdot (\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^n$.

This sum is a number of all n-length paths($L_n$).

Please tell me if my thinkings are right and (if they are right) how to find $lim_{n \to \infty}\chi(L_n)/n$ (I am not very good at finding limits). Thank you in advance.

P.S. I will be also very pleased if you at least tell me how to find my limit.